# How to represent 2 Hadamard gates with Universal set of gates?

Tags: hadamard, universal-gates, quantum-walks

I was reading through Child's Paper on Universal Computation by Quantum Walks: https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.1972

When he discusses how his universal set of gates contains CNOT and the following 2 "widgets":

$$
U_b = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\\ 0 & e^{i \pi / 4} \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
U_c = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} i & 1 \\\ 1 & i \end{pmatrix}
$$

He claims that you can construct a Hadamard gate using these widgets such that:

$$
H = i U_b^2 U_c U_b^2
$$

He ignores the i in his paper, so I'm choosing to temporarily ignore it. He constructs the Hadamard gate for the second of 2 qubits as follows (followed by a CNOT):

[image]

However, I don't believe this would work if you wanted to do a tensor product of Hadamard gates on 2 qubits like $H^{\otimes 2}$. I realize that using the widget's matrix representations, you can do it mathematically, but I'm having trouble visualizing what the graph would look like.

Does anyone know how the graph would look for $H^{\otimes 2}$?